# Get Pseudo-Element Properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to read the CSS properties of a Pseudo Element using JavaScript *getComputedStyle* -

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')[1], ':after').getPropertyValue('top')
```

However the values returned are as '*px*' in Chrome and as '*%*' in Firefox and IE.

Is there a way to get consistent results across all browsers?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing in?

Comment: I am using IE11

Comment: Are you sure the `display` property is the same in both cases? According to https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#resolved-values, the `display` property affects whether the resolved value of `top` is the "used value" (pixels) or the "computed value" (percentage).

Comment: display property is same in both the cases

Answer (score 1):

This could be the culprit...

According to the **[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)** for `window.getComputedStyle()`:

> ### Notes
>
> The values returned by getComputedStyle are known as resolved
>   values. These are usually the same as the CSS 2.1 computed values, but
>   for some older properties like width, height or padding, they are
>   instead the used values. Originally, CSS 2.0 defined the computed
>   values to be the "ready to be used" final values of properties after
>   cascading and inheritance, but CSS 2.1 redefined computed values as
>   pre-layout, and used values as post-layout. For CSS 2.0 properties,
>   the getComputedStyle function returns the old meaning of computed
>   values, now called used values. An example of difference between pre-
>   and post-layout values includes the resolution of percentages that
>   represent the width or the height of an element (also known as its
>   layout), as those will be replaced by their pixel equivalent only in
>   the used value case.

And this **[documentation for used value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value)** is relevant as well.

Comment: so ideally the command getComputedStyle should return only the computed value in pixels and not 'auto' or percentages